# difference between number of bytes

Tags: matlab, memory-management

i could not understand why following thing makes difference

```
A=magic(5);
>> fileid=fopen('magic.txt','w');
>> nbyres=fprintf(fileid,'%5d %5d %5d %5d\n',A)

nbyres =

   150

>> whos
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A           5x5               200  double              
  fileid      1x1                 8  double              
  nbyres      1x1                 8  double
```

for example one command  prints out that side of file is 150byte,while whos command display 250 byte,why is so different?what about additional 50 byte?is  it file name or ?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[`nbytes = fprintf(___)`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#outputarg_nbytes)

returns the number of bytes that `fprintf` writes in your case its 6x24 + 6 = 150.

magic.txt contents: (since you're using only 4 `%5d` with space ), leading to 24 characters on 6 lines + 6 extra

```
   17    23     4    10 
   11    24     5     6
   12    18     1     7
   13    19    25     8
   14    20    21     2
   15    16    22     3
    9
```

`whos` command displays size of `A` as size of 5x5 doubles

Comment: why 6*24+6? what about whos?

Comment: nbyres=fprintf(fileid,'%5d %5d %5d %5d %5d\n',A)

nbyres =

   150

Comment: the same result in this case

Comment: @datodatuashvili yes `%5d` and space too are counted, whats the problem

Comment: so at all formula for calculation number of byte is 5*25+5 right?

Comment: @datodatuashvili No, for `fprintf(fileid,'%5d %5d %5d %5d %5d\n',A` its (5+1) spaces*5 = 30 for each row and you have 5 such row.

Comment: so that means that if we have  n row,in reality matlab will include space also,so we will have  (n+1)  row?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Matlab's ain't including space, you're using space between each `%5d`

Comment: what if i will not use it?and in generally  %5d will help me to display integers right?what is other goals of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57207/discussion-between-dato-datuashvili-and-p0w).

Comment: please discuss it in chart